# How do I turn on search highlighting from a vim script?

Tags: vim

If I do either of the following two:

```
call search("searchString")

exec "/ searchString"
```

From a script, then vim does the search but does not highlight the results, even though hlsearch. Doing the same searches from outside a script highlights the results.

Comment: I just found the answer myself.. always the way. Here it is:

    call search(l:searchString)
    call matchadd('Search', l:searchString)

Comment: Please add your answer as a real answer here. It's hard to spot the comment when you are really looking for an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found out the answer myself:

```
call search(l:searchString)
call matchadd('Search', l:searchString)
```

Comment: Does this allow for the normal use of n/N for next/previous match?

Comment: This really helps!

Comment: @alesplin: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803539/how-do-i-turn-on-search-highlighting-from-a-vim-script/47746577#14087567) answer below says no.  I posted a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803539/how-do-i-turn-on-search-highlighting-from-a-vim-script/47746577#47746577).

Answer (score 4):

The

## **`feedkeys()`**

function is the key (pun intended):

```
call feedkeys("/pattern\<CR>")
```

or cleaner:

```
" highlights – or doesn’t – according to 'hlsearch' option
function SearcH(pattern)
    let @/ = a:pattern
    call feedkeys("/\<CR>")
endfunction
```

Comment: This did work for me. It's similar as using the "n" button after a search. But I have a very very long search string. Is it possible to highlight matches without seeing the search string below?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late. However when I searched for the answer to this problem this page came up. So I feel compelled to help fix it.

> call search(l:searchString)
>
> call matchadd('Search', l:searchString)

Did not work for me. (when run from inside a function) It did higlight the words I wanted to search for but n/N wouldn't cycle between them. Also when I performed a new search the "l:serachStirng" pattern still remained highlighted. This answer on this link worked much better

[Vim search and highlighting control from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765798/vim-search-and-highlighting-control-from-a-script%22Vim%20search%20and%20highlighting%20control%20from%20a%20script%22)

Which gave me:

> let @/ = l:searchString

then run

> normal n

outside the funciton (so the highlighting is done immediately without the user needing to press n)

Answer (score 1):

To turn on, press <kbd>ESC</kbd>  type `:set hls`

To turn off, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> type `:set nohls`

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here:
http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/highlighting-search-results-from-within-a-function-tt5709191.html#a5709193

```

One solution would be

```
function! XXXX() 
    execute '/this' 
    return @/ 
endfunction
```

and to use the following instead of ":call XXXX()".

```
:let @/ = XXXX()
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works from inside a function
(to just enable highlighting and nothing more):

`call feedkeys(":\<C-u>set hlsearch \<enter>")`

Answer (score -3):

You need to put this in your .vimrc file

```
" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif
```

The .vimrc file is usually located in your home directory, or you can find it using "locate .vimrc"

Comment: This is about scripting in vim, not turning on highlighting searches and syntax highlighting in general.